# How to access selected item in TcxEditRepositoryComboBoxItem when looping cxGrid?

Tags: delphi, vcl, tcxgrid

I have a save button on my form which loops through all rows of the tcxgrid and reads its values. I'm trying to read the value of a combo box I have in one of the columns, but I need to read the Key value not the text of it.

```
for I := 0 to tv.DataController.RecordCount - 1 do
begin
  Location := tv.DataController.Values[I, colLocation.Index];
end;
```

colLocation is the combobox, but doing that gives me the text selected not the ItemIndex values. Any clues?

thanks

Comment: colLocation doen't have an items property , the combobox is in a TcxEditRepository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to get the numeric index in the ComboBox Items property of the current grid row, you can do it with code like this

```
procedure TForm1.ProcessComboBox;
var
  I,
  Index : Integer;
  S : String;
  V : OleVariant;
begin
  for I := 0 to tv.DataController.RecordCount - 1 do
  begin
    V := tv.DataController.Values[I, colLocation.Index];
    S := V;
    //  if the RepositoryItem of colLocation is set to cxEditRepository1ComboBoxItem1
    //  you can do
    Index := cxEditRepository1ComboBoxItem1.Properties.Items.IndexOf(S);

    //  OR, if the Properties property of colLocation is set to ComboBox you could do
    //  Index := TcxComboBoxProperties(colLocation.Properties).Items.IndexOf(S);

    S := IntToStr(Index);
    Caption := S;
  end;
end;
```

If that doesn't answer your q, you'd better explain exactly what you *do* want.

Comment: Nice!, that works. I do have a cxEditRepositoryComboBoxItem.